# Hyundai i20 2012

Tags: hyundai, i20

I have a Hyundai i20 2012 model. The car started to loose power, like fuel starvation. This morning the car do not want to start.
I checked all areas...fuel pump and strainer, all fuses, all electrical plugs.
The fuel pump works the moment you cycle the ignition. I investigated all areas, but the last area was fire to the spakplugs.
There was no spark out of the coils.
Can the keycode be lost?
Can it be the electronic board?
Please advise

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Did you actually check pressure at the fuel rail? There are situations where the pump motor runs, but has no output. Without checking the pressure, you just don't know.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I did not test the pump pressure with a pressure hauge. I removed the fuel pressure pipe on the manifold, and there was enough pressure. Enough meaning that when I started loosening the 2 nuts on the flange mounting, the pipe pushes itself out. I cycledctge ignition, and the visible amount of fuel coming out was a ckear indication that there was enough pressure. What concerns ne is that there is no spark on the plugs. I took one coil out with the sparkplug, and there was no spark if I turn the engine with the ignition

Comment: Something to remember, volume does not equal pressure. It appears it all may be working, but with zero back pressure, the flow can be great. Once the pressure is there, flow might be reduced to zero (or near it). It's one of those things you cannot assume is good just from seeing the flow. If the regulator is not working and allow free flow of fuel, there won't be any (or very little) pressure at the injectors, which is the same as no fuel flow at all. Just one way which might be causing your symptoms.

Comment: Thank you for the advise again. I noticed that after all tests, the fuel rail still have a lot of pressure remaining. I have ooened up the flage fitting, andctge pressure popped the o-ring seal! Must the pressure remain in the fuel rack after the engine is switched off?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the problem on my i20.
The timing chain slipped on the intake cam shaft
This is very strange for me. this is the first time that I experience this
The chain slipped the moment the engine kick back after it is switched of
When I turned the engine anti-clockwise, the chain slipped 
I removed the front covert and inspected the tensioner, and this is still in good mechanical working order.
The car services were done to date. The odo reading is 132000km. The chain lasts longer than that. 
I removed the timing chain also, and inspected the chain and found still in order. 
What can be the cause of this?

Comment: Its imperative if you check your engine timing guides as well as the guide tensioner, slipped chain/out of time will destroy your non-interference engine. In these engines the tensioner goes bad , you will need to retime the engine.